# Convert square pulse with 24-volt amplitude to square 5-volt amplitude

Tags: analog, circuit-design, signal

Can anyone help me to make a circuit to Convert square pulse with 24-volt amplitude and has an variable offset voltage to square 5-volt amplitude and offset = 0 ?

I need to take a 24-volt amplitude square pulse with offset sometimes from 0 levels and I need to convert it to a 5-volt without any offset to able to enter it into Microcontroller.

Offset will be vary from 0 to 3 Volt on the signal.

frequency range will be from 0 to 10 Mhz

Thanks,

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so, you need to show what work you have done to attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: use the 24 V signal to drive a relay

Comment: @jsotola or a 24 V fan, blowing at a small turbine with a generator and a rectifier? The possibilities are endless!

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy not assignment i need to make it to drive mictocontroller with signal without offset and 5 volt only

Comment: OK. Please add that it is driving a microcontroller pin in the question. Knowing the load helps narrow down the solutions. When you say that the 24V signal has a variable offset, what do you mean? Can the signal be -24V to 0V? Can it be -12V to 12V? can it be 100V to 124V? Also, what makes the offset change? How often does it change?

Comment: Worlds it suffice to just detect the edges? In that case, a simple capacitor, resistor and maybe a clipping diode might suffice!

Comment: Run it through a photocoupler to an isolated 5V line perhaps?

Comment: If output goes to uC gpio pin and voltage input does not go negative, you could just use resistor and zener diode(s) to achieve a clipped 5V.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I need to take a 24-volt amplitude square pulse with offset sometimes from 0 levels and I need to convert it to a 5-volt without any offset to able to enter it into Microcontroller.
Offset will be from 0 to 3 Volt on the signal

Comment: @Ibrahim, please don't just repeat yourself over and over. Try to answer the questions asked in the comments. Read through them carefully and [edit] your question to include the missing details. Write a proper specification. You have no details on frequency of the signal. It would probably make things much more clear if you explained what is generating this signal.

Comment: Unable to solve unless you define source frequency range, and differential impedance and common mode impedance to ground.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 frequency range will be from 0 to 10 Mhz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to take a 24-volt amplitude square pulse with offset sometimes from 0 levels and I need to convert it to a 5-volt without any offset to able to enter it into Microcontroller.

One might start with a simple voltage divider.
For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR3Olj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming there are no loading issues and precision resistors,

- if the input is between 24V and 27V, the output will be between 4.444V and 5V
- if the input is between 0V and 3V, the output will be between 0V and 0.556V

This should be adequate for driving the logic levels of a gpio pin of a 5V microcontroller.

If you need something more precise, I would add a second stage consisting of a logic level cmos buffer such as the [SN74LVC1G125](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g125.pdf).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjrz37.png)</sup>

The output of this circuit will be

- 0V if Vin < 7.29V
- 5V if Vin > 20.79V

Answer (score 0):

My idea is just the voltage devider is enough. Why we go to unnessesory complications?

Answer (score -1):

Us a comparator, that is what they are for. The LM311 has an open collector output and will operate from 24VDC'